# iRobot vacuum cleaner wakes me up in the middle of the night because it starts vacuuming or annoying me with voice messages

Tags: smart-home, ios

I have two iRobot products

- Roomba e5
- Braava jet m6

Both are connected to WLAN (but internet access is blocked) and I have the iRobot app on my iPhone.

With "Braava jet m6" I have never had problems with it starting to emit audio messages on its own or just wiping. It just does what I tell it to do via the app. That's the way it has to be.

However, the Roomba e5 drives me to despair. I have searched for my problems on the web but find only shopping SPAM and other advertising.

Roomba e5 starts talking in the middle of the night, rarely during the day. I only understood "please charge Roomba", the other stuff I didn't understand.

Today I almost freaked out. At 2:00 it started vacuuming without me asking for it. I then looked in the app and found no indication of his vacuuming action. I do not use smart schedules and other features. I activate the iRobot manually in the app.

Now my question how I can prevent such automatic actions. How can I shutdown those devices completely (no standby)? What went wrong in my setup? I don't use App features, just press the start button.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is only if you are willing  to modify the machine. you can buy a  smart switch and put it between the battery and the mother board and set it to connect the battery only on the day or whatever time you want. You could try sonoff cheap and it gets the job done

https://sonoff.tech/product/diy-smart-switches/basicr2/

or you could unplug the battery when you are sleeping.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bY8ZvVNfxqQ&t=62s

Why am I suggesting such extreme solutions?, well because this model is a bit old and if it's a firmware glitch it won't be fixed since iRobot dropped support.